# Jquery scripts yii2

Tags: jquery, yii2

How can I add a jquery script in mi view in yii 2.0 ? I was searching and i found this command

```
$this->registerJs('$(function ()
    {
        $("#wizard").steps({
            headerTag: "h2",
            bodyTag: "section",
            transitionEffect: "slideLeft"
        });

        $("#wizard-vertical").steps({
            headerTag: "h2",
            bodyTag: "section",
            transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
            stepsOrientation: "vertical"
        });
    });', 3);
```

and the output is this, a javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">$(function ()
    {
        $("#wizard").steps({
            headerTag: "h2",
            bodyTag: "section",
            transitionEffect: "slideLeft"
        });

        $("#wizard-vertical").steps({
            headerTag: "h2",
            bodyTag: "section",
            transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
            stepsOrientation: "vertical"
        });
    });</script>
```

the problem is I need to use it as a JQuery Script like this

```
<script>
        $(function ()
        {
            $("#wizard").steps({
                headerTag: "h2",
                bodyTag: "section",
                transitionEffect: "slideLeft"
            });

            $("#wizard-vertical").steps({
                headerTag: "h2",
                bodyTag: "section",
                transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
                stepsOrientation: "vertical"
            });
        });
    </script>
```

But I don't know how to print a JQuery Script, somebody knows?

Comment: The 2 are pretty much equivalent. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: the question makes no sense....

Comment: jQuery is JS, so its the correct syntax. If its not working, make sure the jQuery-file is loaded and that the JS is executed after the jQuery-load.

Answer (score 3):

you may use this....

update or include jquery code in `app\assets\AppAsset.php` file

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
    ];
    public $js = [    // add required js file....
    'js/jquery.min',
    'js/jquery-scrollToTop',

    ];
    public $jsOptions = [
    'position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD  // include js at <head> tag....
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

so, i hope this ans help you.........:)